# Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to make a simple login that will not crash when you insert into the browser a (") so i needed to parameterize the query string but for some reason im gettin an error saying:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName"

here is the code

```
private void DoSqlQuery() 
{
    try 
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RolaConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkUser = "select * from UserData where UserName = @UserName";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text.Trim());

        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where UserName = @UserName";
            SqlCommand passConn = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
            string password = passConn.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            conn.Close();
            if (password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUserName.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct");
                Response.Redirect("~/LoggedIn.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password is not correct");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Username is not correct");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, pay attention to the case of each character.

Comment: ``@Username`` not equals to ``@UserName``

Comment: In your second query, you have  `SqlCommand` called `passConn`, but you are adding the parameter to `com` - not `passConn` .....

Comment: And also: ***please DO NOT*** store passwords in ***clear text*** in your database!!

Comment: Yes i agree with you. This is for just for a demo how to prevent someone injecting SQL intro the text boxes, or inserting anything in the url to get into the account.

Comment: Just an aside - Please also consider implementing the using pattern to manage those command and connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the wrong command in the inner `if` statement:

```
string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where UserName = @UserName";
SqlCommand passConn = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
^^^--  should be passConn
```

As a result, your second command never gets the parameter added so you get the error you mention. Case sensitivity *may* also be a problem, but it depends on the collation of your database - SQL Server is case-insensitive by default.

Some other suggestions not related to your problem:

- Wrap commands and connection in `using` statements
- Query the username and password in one query (`WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = @Password`).  Hackers will first search for valid usernames, then try to hack the password using dictionary attacks. Trying to find a matching combination is *much* harder.
- Do not store your passwords in plain text - use a [salted hash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602%28v=cs.70%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Or just use built-in security providers rather than rolling your own.

Comment: okay thank you, I got it to work now. I will make those changes thank you for the advice and help.